# How to check if a Number is decimal or not and apply here?

Tags: c++

My code works perfectly fine if the total sum of given elements in `vector a` divided by `2` is an integer, but fails if its a double. So i need to check if the sum is double and if it is return `false`. I tried to do it but its not working.
`TestCase a= [1,2,3,5]`  fails here

```
 bool isPresent(vector<int>& a, vector<int>& v, const double& sum, int i) {
        int n = a.size();
        
        if(i == n) return false;
        if(int(sum) != (sum)) return false; // i tried like this but not working
        if(accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0) == sum) return true; 
        
        if(a[i] <= sum) {
            v.push_back(a[i]);
            for(auto i=v.begin();i!=v.end();i++)
                cout << *i <<" ";
            cout << '\n';
            if(isPresent(a, v, sum, i+1)) 
                return true;
            v.pop_back();
        }
        if(isPresent(a, v, sum, i+1))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    bool canPartition(vector<int>& a) {
        vector<int> v;
        int n = a.size();
        int s=0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            s += a[i];
        }
        double sum = (double)(s/2);
        if((int)sum != sum) return false; // also here
        return isPresent(a, v, sum, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int sum = (double)(s/2);
```

This takes `s` and divides it (as an integer) by `2` (which truncates), then casts the definitely integer result to a `double`, then stores the result back into an `int`, which truncates again. Consider

```
double sum = ((double)s) / 2.0;
```

But you can avoid going through `double` at all by checking the modulo, which tells you the remainder under division.

```
if (s % 2 != 0) return false;
```

Comment: worked thank you. sometimes i feel that these coding languages are stupid. wasted my 2 hrs lol

Comment: sorry it wont allow me to upvote as i am new

Comment: you can also avoid `s % 2 != 0` with `(s & 1) != 0`

Comment: @Yamahari A good compiler will emit efficient code either way with `s % 2 != 0` and `(s & 1) != 0`.  Best to code for clarity.  (For high portability, `(s & 1) != 0` is incorrect functionality with 1s' compliment.)

Comment: With c++20 integers are mandated to be 2s complement, but I get your point

Answer (score 1):

```
int sum = (double)(s/2);
if((int)sum != sum) return false; // also here
```

Like the other answer mentions, this is a bad cast (should be `s/2.`). However, you actually don't need to do this at all. A better way to check whether you can divide by two evenly would be to check the remainder of that division:

```
if(s % 2 != 0) { return false; }
```

Mod (`%`) divides two numbers and gives you the remainder. So if the mod (or remainder) is not 0, then we can't divide evenly.

---

Also note that

```
if(isPresent(a, v, sum, i+1))
    return true;
return false;
```

Can just be

```
return isPresent(a, v, sum, i+1);
```

Comment: i used ```if(s % 1 != 0) { return false; }``` like this before but gave me some shitty error, dont remember what becaue i was crying on this for 2 hrs, will it not give an error if i use ```2``` as u mentioned?

Comment: sorry it wont allow me to upvote as i am new

Comment: Modulus only works for `int`, not `double` @Klaus. So you may have seen that if you were trying to use `sum` instead of `s`. Also, anything `% 1` will always be 0--EVERYTHING divides by 1 evenly!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the bug OP has noticed, ...
... a latent bug: `int(sum)` is undefined when `sum` in not near the `int` range.

```
const double& sum
...
if(int(sum) != (sum)) return false;  // Problem code
```

Instead, use `modf()` to return the fractional part.

```
#include <cmath>

double whole;
double fraction = modf(sum, &whole);
if (fraction != 0.0) return false;
```

Comment: okay now thats a professional way to do it. thanks